# datagdridview display all days of each month between two dates

Tags: c#, datagridview

can someone help me i tried to display all days of months in datagridview c# but it show me in one row instead 15 days for each rows. here is what I need exactly..

[image]

I already did this in listbox and it works fine see image.

[image]

can someone please tell me how to draw and do the same in datagridview, because dgv display one rows for each month, while i want to break it in 15th of month to have 4 rows for each month..

here is what I tried so far in listbox and it works.

```
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
var d1 = dateTimePicker1.Value;
var d2 = dateTimePicker2.Value;
        
for (var dt = d1; dt <= d2; dt = dt.AddMonths(1))
{
    dates.Add(dt);
    int m1days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dates[0].Year, dates[0].Month);
    int m2days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dates[1].Year, dates[1].Month);
    int m3days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dates[2].Year, dates[2].Month);
    var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");

    for (int dayCounter = 1; dayCounter <= m1days; dayCounter++)
    {
        var checked = "";
        if (IsWeekend(Convert.ToDateTime("" + dates[0].Year + "-" + dates[0].Month + "-" + dayCounter + "")))
        {
            checked = "";
        }
        else
        {
            checked = " - X";
        }

        var weekend = ((IsWeekend(Convert.ToDateTime("" + dates[0].Year + "-" + dates[0].Month + "-" + dayCounter + ""))) ? " (Weekend)" : "");
        listBox1.Items.Add(dayCounter  + weekend + "" + checked);
    }

    for (int dayCounter = 1; dayCounter <= m2days; dayCounter++)
    {

        var checked = "";
        if (IsWeekend(Convert.ToDateTime("" + dates[1].Year + "-" + dates[1].Month + "-" + dayCounter + "")))
        {
            checked = "";
        }

        else
        {
            checked = " - X";
        }

        var weekend = ((IsWeekend(Convert.ToDateTime("" + dates[1].Year + "-" + dates[1].Month + "-" + dayCounter + ""))) ? " (Weekend)" : "");
        listBox2.Items.Add(dayCounter + weekend + "" + checked);
    }
}
```

please if someone could help me to achieve the same results of the first above image using datagridview, I will greatly appreciate it!

Thanks in advance!

Edit: here is Iweekend function, i forgot to i

```
private static bool IsWeekend(DateTime date)
        {
            return date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday
                || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday;
        }
```

This is the same code I have, but the one I use it for listbox, can you create or do one for datagidview please?

I already did it in listview and it works..
[image]

But I want the same as this in report viewer to be generated when click button between two dates.

[image]

Comment: The posted code will crash on the line... `int m2days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dates[1].Year, dates[1].Month);` ... since there is no `dates[1]` in the `for` loops first iteration. In addition I get an error with the variable `checked` as from what I can tell… `checked` is a C# keyword. Please edit you question with working and complete code… (where is the `IsWeekend` function?)

Comment: @JohnG I've edited my code and included the IsWeekend function. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried in relation to the `DataGridView`? I do not doubt that you have the code that will do this in two `ListBoxes` as the picture shows, however, the currently posted code will not work for the reasons I described in my previous comment. So, technically the posted code is useless since it does not work nor deal with a `DataGridView`. From the picture, it looks like the grid would have sixteen (16) columns and four (4) rows for each month. Rows 0 and 2 would be the days in the month and rows 1 and 3 would have the “X”’s indicating if the date above is a workday.

Comment: I suggest you create a method, that creates the 16 columns to the grid, then possibly another method that adds four (4) rows for each month. Then loop through the days of the month and set rows 0 and 1 with the day and the “X” value for the first 15 days. Then another loop to set rows 2 and 3 for the rest of the days in that month. As already noted the non-working posted code does not help if you want to do this in a `DataGridView`… please try something using a `DataGridView` first and if you have issues, then post that code.

Comment: @JohnG Sorry, I want say datagridview or tablix of report viewer not datagridview form, because i already done this in listview (see the last attached images), but i want to transform the same idea of listview to tablix of reportviewer, the problem is tablix of reportviewer work with dataset and i don't know how to acheive it with dataset, the code i posted is the same i have and it works..

Comment: @JohnG can I give link to download and see my little app, because code  i posted it works fine, i just need do the same in report viewer tablix that's all, can i send file please?

Comment: I do want to clarify that the posted code “clearly” will crash. This can “easily” be seen with a simple trace using pencil and paper. Follow along please… when the first `for` loop is entered for the “FIRST” time… `dates` is an “EMPTY” list… then… the first line of code “adds” ONE (1) `DateTime` object to the `dates` list with … `dates.Add(dt);`… then two lines later the code tries to get `date[1]` and `date[2]`…when there is clearly ONLY ONE item in the list…? … this clearly WILL NOT WORK.

Comment: At this point it is irrelevant if the code works or not… the code obviously does NOT serve your needs. So I question its purpose altogether. I suggest you create a method that takes a `DateTime` object and returns a `DataTable` with sixteen columns and four rows. A `DataSet` has a `Tables` collection for you to store these `DataTables`. This is obviously going to be a different approach than what you currently have, so the current code is meaningless in this context. Take a closer look at my previous comment, about 16 columns and four rows and how to fill them with data.

Comment: @JohnG if one item in the list it will fail, but i will use try catch , because if user choose less than 2 month it will give error, so the dates[0], dates[1] so it will work.. the problem is report viewer require dataset, and i don't use database for this, how can achieve it, maybe with stored procedure, i am really confused how to implement it in report viewer tablix. Any suggestion? Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Hmmm… your comment… _“if one item in the list it will fail, but i will use try catch , because if user choose less than 2 month it will give error, so the dates[0], dates[1] so it will work.”_ …. NO… it won’t work regardless of how many dates the user selects. … You ask for … _”Any suggestion?”_... ? … I gave two comments that give suggestions on how to do this. I suggested creating a method that takes a date and returns a `DatatTable` with 16 columns and four rows. Is there something wrong with those suggestions?

Comment: Yes, because i didn't understand how to do it, if you are going to post some codes will be helpful for me and anyone having the same issue.